# hash навигация в ajax сайте

Tags: ajax, хеширование

Я хочу сделать сайт без переходов по страницам, тоесть с [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) подгрузкой и с хэшированной навигацией. В гугле я нашёл статьи на хабре, которые датируются 2011 годом (вот [эта](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114911/), например), видимо приуроченные к выходу ВК, а фильтр на последние пару лет не даёт результатов. На то время новинками были `pjax` и `djax`.

Дак вот я хотел узнать, изменилось ли что-нибудь в этой сфере за 6 лет? Появились ли новые технологии? Можете ткнуть меня носом на актуальную статью или прямо здесь вкратце описать что и как нужно использовать, чтобы не оказаться мамонтом?

Comment: и зачем же сделать без страниц? так поисковики не смогут нормально индексировать ваш сайт

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan Вконтакту, кажется, это не мешает. К тому же у меня, как и в ВК, на сайте будет музыка, которая не должна прерываться при переходах по страницам.

Answer (score 2):

На сегодняшний день такие сайты называются веб-приложениями aka SPA.
Single Page Application - загружается страница, все остальное взаимодействие просходит уже без перезагрузки страницы, приложение ведет себя подобно нативному десктопному/мобильному приложению.

SPA, как правило, не пишут вот так, просто на ajax, а используют javascript библиотеки или фреймворки. Наиболее популярые сейчас Angular, React, Vue.js. Каждый фреймворк имеет инструменты для работы с навигацией по history, будь то хеш-навигация или замена path целиком.

Для примера, если вы пишете приложение на React, то, скорее всего, вам подойдет библиотека react-router (не могу добавить ссылку, гуглите).

По поводу индексации поисковыми роботами, для упомянутых выше фреймворков есть поддержка server side rendering, что позволяет отрисовывать страницу на сервере, а в браузере javascript подхватывает отрисованное состояние и продолжает работу интерактивно.

Если уж совсем так по хардкору, безо всяких библиотек, то можно использовать history API, а отлавливать события перехода (назад/вперед) через window.onpopstate.

PS: к сожалению все ссылки пришлось убрать, т.к. репутация пока не позволяет их размещать. В

Comment: Спасибо, очень информативно. Но вот дело ещё в том, что у меня уже сделана большая часть проекта на jquery, я сейчас лишь хочу внедрить эту SPA. Не будет ведь ничего криминального, если поставить React лишь для того, чтобы использовать react-router или лучше искать решение для библиотеки, на которой я работаю?

Comment: Ссылки играют второстипенную роль, более важно как Вы сами аргументируете ответ. Пользуйтесь копи+паста со сторонних источников, если это необходмо.